# using wildcard to select names that starts with specific character not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use wildcard to select all names in first_name column that starts with 'b','s', or 'p' by using

```
SELECT first_name
from actor
where first_name like '[bsp]%';
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified which version of MySQL you're using, which changes the level of support for regular expressions. A backward-compatible version (back to MySQL ~v5.x) uses:

1. The regular expression pattern `.*` in place of the MySQL `%` wildcard
2. [The `regexp` token](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) to declare that the condition should be interpreted as a regular expression

```
SELECT first_name from actor where first_name regexp '[bsp].*?';
```

[<sup>SQLFiddle</sup>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e17e68/9)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
SELECT first_name
from actor
where first_name like 'b%' or first_name like 's%' or first_name like 'p%';
```

Answer (score 0):

This work as well:

```
SELECT first_name FROM actor WHERE first_name REGEXP '^b|^s|^p';
```

Tested on MySQL 4.1 and MariaDB 10.3.10

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is a regular expression:

```
where first_name regexp '^[bsp]';
```

Unlike `like` patterns, regular expressions do not need to match the entire expression.  `regexp` returns true if the pattern matches anywhere.  Hence, the equivalent of `%` is not needed (which would be `.*` in a regular expression).

You could also use:

```
where left(first_name, 1) in ('b', 's', 'p')
```